# Share computer's network connection with wireless access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a Windows 7 PC connected via Wi-Fi to a DSL router. I would like to use this PC to extend the network by sharing its connection via Ethernet to Belkin F5D7231-4 wireless router. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you not able to directly connect the Belkin router to the DSL router via Ethernet cable?

Comment: @iglvzx I can, but I want to extend the range of my network.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to switch off DHCP on the Belkin F5 first.

Then connect the Belkin to the Windows ethernet port.  Go to the W7 start menu, and type "View Network Connections" in the search box, then select it from the list.

Right click the wifi network card, and select properties, then go to the Sharing tab.

Enable `Allow other network users to connect` and disable the `Allow other network users to control` if you like.

This will enable connection sharing, and will start a DHCP server on the LAN interface.  So anyone on connecting to the Belkin F5 wifi will request an IP address, and your Windows box will respond, and act as gateway to the internet.